# Excel macro to assemble word documents

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I take into account to modify my macro code for optimization due to:
My macro creates for each line of the excel file a new document and saves it under the name of the 2nd column of row j .. and as result I 'to get an excel file with 5 lines, 5 word document with multiple users and the number becomes huge! So I would like to assemble in one single word document, I mean, instead of creating a new line for each document, the macro should create a new page in a single document, and as result I would get with only 1 word document 5 pages for an excel file 5 online. is - Can I please??

Code:

```
Sub MacroAutoJB() 

Dim WordApp As Word.Application 
Dim WordDoc As Word.Document 
Dim oWdApp As Object 

Dim i As Byte 
Dim sChemin As String 
Dim wb As Workbook 

Dim OutApp As Object 
Dim OutMail As Object 
Dim strbody As String 

On Error Resume Next 
Dim nom As String 
Dim sName As String 
Dim sPath As String 

On Error Resume Next 
Dim j As Integer 
j = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count 'count number of lines used in the file

Dim n As Byte 
n = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 

If ActiveWorkbook.Name Like "WPaie*.xls" Then 

    user = Environ("username") 
    sName = ActiveWorkbook.Name 
    sPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\" & user & "\My Documents\" 
    sName = Replace(sName, ".xls", "_Word") 
    MkDir sName 

    For j = 2 To j 'start the loop the opeation until the next will be for each line used in the file

        Set WordApp = CreateObject("word.application") 
        nom = Sheets(1).Cells(j, 2) 
        mail = Sheets(1).Cells(2, n) 

        Set oWdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application") 
        Set WordDoc = oWdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\" & user & "\Class.doc") 

        For i = 1 To n - 1 
            WordDoc.Bookmarks("Sig" & i).Range.Text = Cells(j, i) 
        Next i 

        WordDoc.Bookmarks("Signet").Range.Text = Cells(j, 2) 
        WordDoc.Bookmarks("Sigmail").Range.Text = Cells(j, n) 

        WordDoc.SaveAs Filename:=sPath & sName & "\" & nom & ".doc" 
        WordApp.Visible = False 
        oWdApp.Quit 
        ActiveDocument.Close True 
        WordApp.Quit 

    Next j 
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

Comment: My Macro work But I tried to assemble multiple Word document creating by this macro in one document .. I tried to do : "Set WordDoc = oWdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\" & user & "\Class.doc")"  but this not works !! every time I have a new document and its not good , I must have one doc word . thnks